# Why my Data model aren't upload in my tableviewcontroller

Tags: swift, uitableview

I don't know why I can't view my pets in the table.

Few days ago the app is working perfect but when I updated the last version of Xcode the app crashed, I can't see the data whet the App run.

I new developer in swift

Help me, please.

------------------------------Model------------------------

```
import UIKit

struct InfoPet{

    let PetPicture: String
    let PetBackground: String
    let PetName: String
    let PetAge: String

    static func InfoPets() -> [InfoPet]{
        let pet1 = InfoPet(PetPicture: "Drako", PetBackground: "Background Can", PetName: "Drako", PetAge: "2 years old")
        let pet2 = InfoPet(PetPicture: "Lucky", PetBackground: "Background Cat", PetName: "Lucky", PetAge: "3 years old")

        return [pet1, pet2]
    }

}
```

---

-----------------------TableViewController----------------

```
class PetsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Global Var

    var pets: [InfoPet] = InfoPet.InfoPets()


    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pets.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PetCell", for: indexPath) as! PetsTableViewCell
        let pet =  pets[indexPath.row]

        cell.pet = pet

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDalegate

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}
```

---

-----------------------tableViewCell-----------------------

```
class PetsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ImgPhotoPet: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ImgBackgroundPet: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var LblNamePet: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var LblAgePet: UILabel!

    var pet: InfoPet!{
        didSet{
            updateUI()
        }
    }

    func updateUI() {
        ImgBackgroundPet.image = UIImage(named: pet.PetBackground)
        ImgPhotoPet.image = UIImage(named: pet.PetPicture)
        ImgPhotoPet.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        ImgPhotoPet.layer.masksToBounds = true
        LblNamePet.text = pet.PetName
        LblAgePet.text = pet.PetAge
    }

}
```

---

Comment: What is the error message on crash ?

Comment: in this case your delegate functions are not calling, kindly check your delegate and data source functions are calling or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add Cell Identifier as "PetCell"

and add viewDidLoad method in PetsTableViewController class.

create IBOutlet of the table view.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableview.dataSource = self
    tableview.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I
I fixed it simply related to the method TableViewController to the graphic part. 
beginner error, but you give me that idea